# Symmetric interval on an integer ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups, symmetry

$\mathbb{Z}_p=\{0,1,..,p-1\}$ for some positive integer $p$.

How can we define $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the interval of $(-\frac{p}{2}, \frac{p}{2}] \cap \mathbb{Z}$?

For example. if $p=7$, I can understand $\mathbb{Z}_8=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6, 7\}$.
But, I couldn't understand the mapping between $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6, 7\} $ and  $\{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}.$

What is the mapping of each element?

Comment: $0\equiv0,1\equiv1,2\equiv2,3\equiv3,4\equiv4,5\equiv-3,6\equiv-2,7\equiv-1$. But really, it is better to think of $\Bbb Z_n$ as a quotient of $\Bbb Z$, not as a subset of $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{Z}_8=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6, 7\}\equiv \{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$$

Note that   in  $ \mathbb{Z}_8 $ we have $5=-3, 6=-2,$ and $7=-1$

The use of negative makes some computations easier specially when dealing with absolute values or $\pm $ notation.

For example $$ \mathbb{Z}_5 = 0,\pm 1, \pm2 $$

$$ \mathbb{Z}_9 = 0,\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \pm 4$$

Comment: Great answer! Do you have more examples that make use of negative? From software engineering perspective, is there any efficiency difference between integers with negative and integers without negative?

Comment: No related to software engineering. Mostly in number theory the use of negatives is helpful. For example$ 35^{20} \equiv (-1)^{20}=1 \pmod {36}$

Comment: Oh, we can reduce the bit length of the absolute value!

Comment: And... are there any names for using negation? Negative integer ring? I do not know.. How can we differentiate ℤ8={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} and  ℤ8={−3,−2,−1,0,1,2,3,4} by name?

Comment: I would go with central representation of $\mathbb {Z}_8$